# How to filter blank entries returned from DB query

Tags: powershell

I have a SQL query which pulls DeviceName, Primary, Secondary, and Tertiary from a table:

```
$SQLQuery= (Invoke-Sqlcmd  -Serverinstance $ServerInstance -Database $Database -Query "select DeviceName, Primary, Secondary, Tertiary from dbo.Table")
```

I then throw those entries into a hash table with the Primary/Secondary/Tertiary as an array in the value:

```
$DeviceList = @{}
foreach ($item in $SQLQuery)
{
if($item.Primary -and $item.Secondary -and $item.Tertiary)
{
    $DeviceList += @{$item.DeviceName = "$($item.Primary)", "$($item.Secondary)", "$($item.Tertiary)"}
}
elseif ($item.Primary -and $item.Secondary -and !$item.Tertiary)
{
    $DeviceList += @{$item.DeviceName = "$($item.Primary)", "$($item.Secondary)"}
}
elseif ($item.Primary -and !$item.Secondary -and !$item.Tertiary)
{
    $DeviceList  += @{$item.DeviceName = "$($item.Primary)"}
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that the SQL query can return blank results which are NOT `NULL`. Which makes `$DeviceList` look like this:

```
$devicelist = @{
    "Device1" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com";
    "Device7" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com";
    "Device8" = "Jane.Doe@Domain.com";
    "Device2" = "Bob.Davis@domain.com", "Jane.Doe@domain.com";
    "Device3" = "Bob.Davis@domain.com", "";
    "Device4" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "", "Bob.Davis@domain.com";
    "Device5" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com", "Bob.Davis@domain.com";
    "Device6" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com", ""
}
```

I can filter these by throwing in a repetitive if statement such as:

```
elseif ($item.Primary -and !$item.Secondary -and !$item.Tertiary)
{
    if($item.Primary -ne '')
    {
    $DeviceList  += @{$item.DeviceName = "$($item.Primary)"}
    }
}
```

But that's incredibly repetitive, and time consuming. I can also modify the SQL query to disregard those, but I'd much prefer to keep the SQL query simple and do the filtering in PowerShell. There has to be an easier way to do that.

The end result that I am looking for is that if the entry is blank, it just gets skipped over, so `$DeviceList` would look like this:

```
$devicelist = @{
    "Device1" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com";
    "Device7" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com";
    "Device8" = "Jane.Doe@Domain.com";
    "Device2" = "Bob.Davis@domain.com", "Jane.Doe@domain.com";
    "Device3" = "Bob.Davis@domain.com";
    "Device4" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com",  "Bob.Davis@domain.com";
    "Device5" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com", "Bob.Davis@domain.com";
    "Device6" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com"
}
```

If my issue doesn't make sense, please let me know and I will try to clarify. As always, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build-up the list per device incrementally:

```
$DeviceList = @{};
foreach ($item in $SQLQuery)
{
    $arr = @();
    if($item.Primary -ne $null -and $item.Primary -ne [System.DBNull]::Value -and $item.Primary -ne '')
    {
        $arr += "$($item.Primary)";
    }
    if($item.Secondary -ne $null -and $item.Secondary -ne [System.DBNull]::Value -and $item.Secondary -ne '')
    {
        $arr += "$($item.Secondary)";
    }
    if($item.Tertiary -ne $null -and $item.Tertiary -ne [System.DBNull]::Value -and $item.Tertiary -ne '')
    {
        $arr += "$($item.Tertiary)";
    }
    if ($arr.count -gt 0)
    {
        $DeviceList += @{$item.DeviceName = $arr};
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if `Invoke-Sqlcmd` will return `NULL` or `DBNull`, so I've included a check for both.

Comment: Andy, actually your first answer worked perfectly after I changed `$arr =@{}` to `$arr=@()` . You just made my life so much easier, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

An example with WMI since I don't have SQL installed:

```
(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Bios).PSObject.Properties|? Value -ne $NULL|ft Name, Value
```

This will return only the non-null properties, but will lose all Win32_Bios class functionality. I assume this should be fine given the context of your code.